# How to ignore parent fetch in entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi I want to ignore the parent fetch while I am calling child tables at the entity level. What kind of annotation I can use?

Answer (score 0):

ManyToOne's fetch type is by default EAGER, so you need to explicitly state that you want to use LAZY fetch:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```